# libgdx - is the preferences file saved after I delete the app or update it?

Tags: android, preferences, status, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx for game development,
I want to use the preferences Class to save my game status, 
my question is: where this file saved, and will the file be deleted after the user will update my game?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On android it is saved as [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
on desktop it saved as xml type file in user/preferenceName dir

and no it shouldn't be deleted after udpate, it won't be deleted/modifed unless you (or the user) do it.

also if you delete the app on android it will be deleted.

Comment: If it is a SharedPreference on Android it will be deleted if the app is uninstalled but not when the app is updated.